# KnockoutJS: wait until all throttled computed observables are evaluated

Tags: knockout.js, throttling

Is there any possibility to wait until all throttled computed observables in a ViewModel are evaluated.

I have a heavy ViewModel with a lot of such observables. And sometimes I need to get it's plain JS representation right after populating it from JSON, but when I try to do that some observables are not evaluated yet.

I have tried to implement a kind of async `toJS`, but it doesn't work as expected. Am I doing something wrong there or it's not possible at all?

```
toJSasync = function (vm) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred(),
      waiter = ko.computed(function () {
         return ko.toJS(vm);
      });

  deferred.resolve( waiter() );

  deferred.always(function () {
    waiter.dispose();
  });

  return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: resolve your deferred inside the computed. you are resolving the deferred immediately, which will result in the done functions firing. move the resolve inside teh computed function.

Comment: Computed is being evaluated during creation to detect dependencies. If I will move "resolve" inside, it will be resolved immediately anyway.

Comment: Could you post an example viewmodel?